# How to ensure thread safety for Java reflection's set operation?

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent

Is Field public void set(Object obj, Object value) thread-safe when using Java reflection? If it's not thread-safe, how can the atomicity of set be ensured?

Write rarely and read frequently, reads and writes are not in the same place, so it's not convenient to use synchronized access.

Comment: There is no one-sided thread safety. All access to shared mutable data must be coordinated in a compatible way. Whether you use Reflection or ordinary field access, is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [VarHandle](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/invoke/VarHandle.html) to perform finer-grained access to a variable than with default reflection.

> Access to such variables is supported under various access modes, including plain read/write access, volatile read/write access, and compare-and-set.

You can also manually create load/store/full fences. Prerequisites are: understanding the Java Memory Model and concurrency in general.